# jface tableviewer cell-span

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-pde

I am endeavouring to render some hierarchic data in a `TableViewer` (the `TreeViewer` isn't a good fit - trust me on this :-). Consequently I need to render the parent cells with a row-span > 1.

As far as I can tell, this currently isn't possible with the regular JFace `TableViewer`, or the SWT `Table` underneath.

Can anyone tell me I'm wrong?

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

You could use a TreeViewer displayed in a "table mode", like illustrated by [this class](https://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=swt-jface:treetableviewer).

[image]
<sub>(source: [sowas.com](http://javawiki.sowas.com/lib/exe/fetch.php?w=&h=&cache=cache&media=swt-jface:jface-columntree.png))</sub>

However, since a TreeViewer is not an option for you, you could take some idea from the code of [TableTree](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratesTableTreeTableTree.htm), even though it has [been deprecated in eclipse3.3](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=130608).

[image]
<sub>(source: [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/TableTreeTest.PNG))</sub>

[TableTreeViewer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100929163409/http://www.koders.com:80/java/fidE59BDDB5C3D65FC7B6AEA62AED6EDB9CA3A466C3.aspx) and [TableTree](http://www.koders.com/java/fid51495023BFCC9412DE393517380F2B975EA1F484.aspx?s=file%3aTableTree.java) are both based on a Table.

Comment: Thanks Von. If neither TreeViewer nor TableViewer can do it - are there any 3rd party controls that you know of that may fit this role?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried nebulas grid http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php.

[image]

Comment: [Your wish has come true](https://eclipse.org/nebula/downloads.php) a few years ago.